# Как в сетке bootstrap задействовать половинчатые элементы?

Tags: css, bootstrap, изображения

Есть блок картинок с сеткой на `bootstrap`, которые хочу сделать таким образом: на разрешениях `1920px` и выше, чтобы выводилось по 6 картинок в 2 ряда целиком, а при меньших разрешениях до `1200px` - 4 картинки целиком и 2 половинчатые по бокам слева и справа. Пробовал делать через стили для

```
.row {
 width:120%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Но, к сожалению, скрытие переполнения не срабатывает. Как правильно это можно сделать?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video1">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video2">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video3">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video4">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video1">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video3">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video5">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video6">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video7">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video8">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video5">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a class="video-box" href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="video7">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Responsive utilities](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/) может скрывать и показывать блок при разных разрешениях экрана, на 1 блок можно наложить 2 класса, скрой когда > и показывай когда <

Comment: @RifmaMan поясните, как свойства `hidden` использовать на половину элемента?

Comment: Посмотрите `.hidden-lg-down` и `.hidden-xl-up` я думаю изначально нужно подгружать все 6 блоков и дать боковым класс `.hidden-lg-down` (плюс еще 2 по бокам половинчатые но скрытые добавив класс `.hidden-xl-up`). Но тут я не уверен что правильно написал, стоит поиграться с классами.